# Sprechen von Synonymen und über Synonyme

Tags: discussion

Die knappe [Ja-Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/20373/266) zur Frage, ob von und über etwas sprechen gleichbedeutend sind, wurde gelöscht. Ich hätte sie gerne aufgewertet, weil ich sie für die richtige Antwort halte.

> I would say sprechen von/über are interchangeable.

Richtig ist zwar, dass keine Begründung geliefert wird, aber welche Art von Begründung käme in Frage?

Die anderen Antworten basteln sich eifrig Erklärungen zurecht. Kilian Foth hält die Alternativen für nahezu ununterscheidbar. 
Dann wirft er doch einen Trend ins Rennen, den er ausgemacht haben will, benennt aber keinen Zeitraum, in dem der Trend stattfand, wahrscheinlich weil er gar keinen Trend meint, sondern etwas anderes. 
Dann behauptet er, dass das eine, je nach Kontext, häufiger benutzt wird als das andere. Häufiger heißt aber nicht richtig. Ob ich sage "Ich geh in den Supermarkt" oder "Ich geh in den Discounter" - beides ist richtig und synonym. Das häufiger Übliche ist aber nicht besser. Es ist nur häufiger.

Man kann auch nicht rechtfertigen zu empfehlen so zu sprechen, weil es häufiger sei.

Dass man im nächsten Beispiel ebenso gut sagen könnte "Er spricht über AIDS" wird hoffentlich niemand bestreiten. Inwiefern der erste Satz die Auflistung eines Themas sein soll, das zweite nicht, bleibt völlig im Dunkeln.

Eine funktionierende Erklärung ist im Posting nicht auszumachen, nur willkürliche Behauptungen die durch die Beispiele gar nicht gestützt werden. Viele Worte um nichts.

Avigrails Antwort ist eine noch längere Katastrophe. 
Erst fasst er Kilians Antwort falsch zusammen. Es ist schon kategorial ein Fehler, denn wenn jemand über Personen spricht, sind diese sein Topic. Da hat wieder jemand Birnen mit Obst verglichen.

> You usually talk about a topic and generalize it to some point.

Das ist mir neu. Jemand, der über eine Sache redet, verallgemeinert sie bis zu einem Punkt? Wenn Onkel von seinem (aka: über seinen) Autounfall spricht, dann folgt immer auch eine Betrachtung von Unfällen im Allgemeinen?

> The German "über" does the same just like in "Übersicht".

Was?
Das Deutsche macht dasselbe wie wer oder was? Der angesprochene Leser, bzw. ein unspezifischer 'man'. Es spricht auch von Dingen und verallgemeinert sie? 
Und ein Beispiel dafür ist "Übersicht"?

Das ist doch Kraut und Rüben. 14 Leute sagen "Daumen hoch". Wir haben zwar auch nichts verstanden, aber es sind schon mal Worte gemacht. Sogar "über" kam drin vor, das ist ja irgendwie Thema, wie in *überzeugen*.

> You ask somebody to tell you about something to get an impression.

Ok. Nun haben wir einen spekulativen Dialog, den wir uns vorstellen sollen, zusammen mit einer behaupteten Motivation.

> When I tell you something about a topic I am giving you more like a summary so you get the idea.

Der imaginäre Dialogpartner antwortet und die Konversation gelingt.

> When I talk *of* a certain topic I (maybe) want to convince/win you.

Ja, oder maybe not.

> I think the contents are more important here.

Oder maybe not.

Was ist das hier? Wenn ich jemanden überzeugen will spreche ich von einer Sache. Bei einer Zusammenfassung dagegen über eine Sache? Leider sind jetzt etwas zusammenzufassen und jmd. überzeugen zu wollen weder disjunkt, noch erschöpfend.

Dann erfahren wir noch, dass es Avigrail nicht behagt nur über die Natur oder von der Natur zu reden. Wieso weiß niemand, was die Relevanz für das Thema ist wissen wir auch nicht, aber prima, es verlängert die Antwort. Wahrscheinlich ist sie falsch, aber sie ist länger und nett formatiert.

Dann kommt die Zusammenfassung: Geht es um Zusammenfassungen, so benutzt man über, geht es um Details benutzt man von.

Das funktioniert schon deswegen nicht, weil eine Zusammenfassung aus einer anderen Perspektive betrachtet doch nur ein Detail ist, und jedes Detail aus einer anderen Perspektive eine Zusammenfassung.

```
Mutter sprach von ihrer Krankheit.
Sie sprach über ihre Lage. 

Mutter sprach über ihre Krankheit.
Sie sprach von Husten, Schnupfen, Übelkeit.
```

Die Beispiele werden auf Englisch gegeben, damit implizit behauptend, das sei im Englischen und im Deutschen gleich. Das ist nach meinem Kenntnisstand keine Prämisse, auf die man sich unbegründet stützen kann.

Angesichts solch schlechter Antworten sieht man leicht, dass die Qualität einer Antwort nicht in ihrer Länge liegt und nicht alles, was sich als Erklärung gibt, ist auch eine.

Bei Synonymverdacht ist das ein häufiges Problem hier. Die Leute spinnen sich ad hoc was zurecht, was sie nirgends zuvor je erörtert haben, auch nie irgendwo gelesen haben und entsprechend fragil ist es.

Comment: Warum ist das eine Frage auf meta? Ist das überhaupt eine Frage?

Comment: Es ist keine Frage, sondern ein Diskusssionsbeitrag, daher mit "discussion" getagt.

Comment: OK, was ist denn dann die These, die diskutiert werden soll? Für mich sieht das eher nach einem Rant über den spezifischen Thread aus. Aber ich kann daraus wenig verallgemeinerbares ableiten.

Comment: Es geht darum, eine kurze Antwort nicht einfach zu schließen, weil sie kurz ist. Was hätte derjenige dem "I would say sprechen von/über are interchangeable." dem als Begründung hinzufügen sollen?

Answer (score 3):

Wenn ich das richtig verstehe, geht es hier also um die Frage, ob die Regel sinnvoll ist, nach der kurze Antworten geschlossen werden.

Die Regel ist sinnvoll.

1. Die Kürze der Antwort sagt zwar nichts über ihren Wahrheitsgehalt aus. Auch kurze Antworten können wahr sein. Aber: Jede wahre Antwort kann begründet werden. Und eine begründete Antwort ist immer besser als eine nicht begründete Antwort. Wer die wahre Antwort kennt, ist in der Regel auch in der Lage eine Begründung zu geben. Die Regel schafft einen Anreiz, diese Begründung auch zu schreiben.
2. Aus der Regel, dass zu kurze Antworten schlecht sind, folgt nicht, dass lange Antworten (per se) gut seien. Auch lange Antworten können und sollen negativ bewertet werden, wenn sie schlecht sind.

Im konkreten Fall hätten zum Beispiel Beispiele die Antwort verbessert, die belegen, dass die beiden Synonyme wirklich austauschbar sind. Auch eine Erörterung der strittigen Fälle wäre hilfreich gewesen.

Comment: Dass die Wörter synonym sind, kannst man mit Beispielen nicht zeigen, einmal weil ohnehin schwer zu zeigen ist, dass zwei Aussagen das Gleiche bedeuten, wie sich an den vielen Beiträgen zeigt, die unterschiedliche Bedeutungen behaupten die meist aus nichts, als Formulierungsvorlieben bestehen. Zweitens müsste man ja erschöpfend alle Verwendungen auflisten, denn die Unterschiede könnten sich ja bei den Beispielen zeigen, die man unterschlagen hat.

Comment: @userunknown Im strengen Sinne kann man keine allgemeine Aussage mit Beispielen nie beweisen. Man kann sie aber mit Beispielen plausibilisieren, und das hat dann auch einen Mehrwert. Wenn du es formaler willst: Jedes Positivbeispiel verringert die Wahrscheinlichkeit der Nullhypothese :-) Auch wenn man niemals alle Beispiele aufzählen kann, ist es dennoch sinnvoll, einige aufzuzählen.