# Antworten, die absolute Synonymität behaupten / Answers that claim absolute synonymity

Tags: discussion, answers

Wir erhalten nicht wenige Fragen nach dem Unterschied zwischen zwei Wörtern o. Ä. Ab und zu schreibt jemand einen Kommentar oder eine Antwort, dass es keinen Unterschied gebe, ohne eine großartige Begründung zu liefern, zum Beispiel [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/53800/2594).

Dies führt mehrere Probleme mit sich:

- [Absolute Synonymität ist äußerst selten, wenn sie denn überhaupt existiert.](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/2062/1822) Die besten Kandidaten sind Fälle wie *Samstag* und *Sonnabend,* wo ein Auseinanderdriften der Bedeutungen durch den Vorrang unseres Zeitsystems vermieden wird (was aber jetzt einen Unterschied im Register nicht ausschließt). Antworten, die absolute Synonymität behaupten, sind daher sehr wahrscheinlich falsch oder werden erst mit einer Begründung nützlich.
- Die Abwesenheit eines Unterschiedes zu belegen ist naturgemäß schwer. Beispiele reichen nicht. Bestenfalls kann man zu generellen Argumenten greifen (wie ich für *»Samstag* vs. *Sonnabend«* oben).
- Antworten und Kommentare, die Gleichheit behaupten, können fälschlicherweise »gewinnen«, [weil sie zuerst da sind](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731/255554).
- Solche Antworten führen häufig zu den gleichen allgemeinen Diskussionen (mit Argumenten wie den obigen).

Wie sollen wir mit solchen Antworten umgehen?

Dieses Problem wurde [hier](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1493/2594) schon einmal angerissen.

---

A prominent type of questions on our site is asking for differences between two words or similar. Every now and then these questions receive answers claiming that there is no difference without much elaboration, for example [this one](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/53800/2594).

These lead to several problems:

- [Absolute synonymity is very rare, if it exists at all](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/2062/1822). The best candidates are cases like *Samstag* and *Sonnabend,* where the primacy of our time system prevents a divergence of meanings (there still may be a difference in register though). Answers claiming absolute synonymity are therefore very likely to be wrong or will only become useful with an explanation.
- The absence of a difference is naturally more difficult to prove. Examples do not suffice. At best, one can make a general argument (as I did for *Samstag* vs. *Sonnabend* above).
- Answers and comments claiming absolute synonymity can prevail despite being wrong thanks to being [the fastest gun in the West](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731/255554).
- Such answers tend to attract redundant general discussions (in the line of the above).

How should we handle such answers?

This problem has been previously mentioned [here](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1493/2594).

Comment: Die Definition von absoluter Synonymität scheint zu sein, dass man in JEDEM Satz die beiden Wörter austauschen kann. Aber das sagt meiner Meinung nach nicht aus, ob zwei Wörter die gleiche Bedeutung haben. Grundsätzlich - ohne jetzt irgendwelche Beweise anzuführen - können zwei Wörter mit identischer Bedeutung eine andere Grammatik erwarten oder ein Wort kann trotz identischer Bedeutung im Zusammenhang mit bestimmten anderen Wörter nicht idiomatisch sein.

Comment: Ein anderer Aspekt reden wir von Wörter oder von eienr konkreten Bedeutung eines Wortes? Ein Wort kann zwei Bedeutungen haben und im Sinne der ersten Bedeutung stets 1:1 durch ein anderes Wort ersetzt werden. In der Hinsicht sind die zwei Wörter schlicht zwei Representanten für die entsprechende Bedeutung. Das eines der Wörter noch eine zweite Bedeutung hat, kann bei gängigen Wörter von Wichtigkeit sein, wenn die zweite Bedeutung aber literarisch, veraltet, regional oder aus sonstigen Gründen selten, dürfte sie für Deutschlernende unwichtig sein.

Comment: Worauf ich nur hinaus will, dass ich durchaus die Aussage deines verlinkten Beispiels "gestehen und zugeben sind identlisch" nachvollziehen kann und nicht als schlichtweg falsch abstempeln würde. Das die Aussage irreführend und nicht hilfreich ist — und darüberhinaus nicht das Mindestmaß einer vernünftigen Antwort erreicht — stelle ich selbstredend nicht in Zweifel.

Answer (score 2):

Falsche Antworten sind auch Antworten. Gelöscht werden sollten grundsätzlich nur Antworten, die a) keine Antworten sind, oder b) handwerklich total schlecht sind. Unsere Aufgabe als User ist es, falsche Antworten mit Downvotes zu kennzeichnen, sodass sie im Zweifelsfall automatisch gelöscht werden. Ich sehe keinen kategorischen Unterschied zwischen Antworten, die absolute Synonymität behaupten, und anderen mehr oder weniger klar falschen Antworten.

Um [diesen Post zu zitieren](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/778/15277):

- [A]ny post that is not an answer (should be a comment, doesn't answer the question, etc.) should be deleted. Answers that are wrong or that dispense poor advice should be downvoted, not deleted.
- An answer that is not an answer should be deleted (should be a comment, doesn't answer the question etc...).
- Answers that are answers but are factually wrong or are actively bad (say promote SQL Injection) should get downvoted, but not deleted.

Comment: Klar. Wir können aber als Community entscheiden, dass wir gewisse falsche Antworten nicht haben möchten. In diesem Fall sind die Antworten ja noch nicht einmal zwangsläufig falsch, nur nutzlos. Es ist ungefähr so, als würde jemand »Keine Ahnung« als Antwort schreiben – das mag zwar richtig sein, bringt aber niemanden weiter.

Answer (score 1):

Absolute Synonymität ist eine außerordentliche Behauptung und [bedarf daher außergewöhnlicher Beweise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagan_standard).

Dass es einen Unterschied gibt, sollte die Grundannahme für solche Fragen sein. Wem kein Unterschied einfällt, der soll annehmen, dass er ihn schlichtweg nicht gefunden hat und daher die Frage nicht beantworten kann. Das beste Argument für absolute Synonymität, das wir bieten können, ist wohl, dass niemand die entsprechende Frage beantworten kann. Wer eine Antwort schreibt, die absolute Synonymität behauptet, soll erklären, warum diese im konkreten Fall ausnahmsweise vorliegt.

Antworten (und Kommentare), die absolute Synonymität behaupten, ohne ein konkretes Argument zu bringen, sollen mit Verweis auf diese Meta-Frage gelöscht werden. Sie sind so wertvoll wie Antworten, die nichts weiteres sagen als: »Ich kenne die Antwort nicht.« Dies umfasst Antworten, deren Verfasser sich darauf beruft, Muttersprachler zu sein (da es nicht konkret zur gegeben Frage ist).

---

Absolute synonymity is an exraordinary claim and thus [requires extraordinary evidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagan_standard).

The default assumption for questions asking for differences should be that a difference exists. If you cannot think of a difference, you should assume that you just haven’t found and thus cannot answer the question. Arguably the best evidence for absolute synonymity we can provide is that nobody can answer the respective question. Only when you can argue that absolute synonymity exceptionally holds in the specific case, you can post an answer saying so.

Answers (and comments) that claim that there is no difference and do not provide an argument for the specific case in question should be deleted with a link to this meta question. They are as valuable as answers saying just: “I don’t know.” This includes answers where the author claims authority due to being a native speaker (since that is not specific to the question).

Comment: Daß es keine echten Synonyme gibt, ist eine Platitüde. Ironischerweise habe ich nicht mit den angesprochenen Antworten, sondern mit den Fragen ein Problem. Diese sind häufig so gestellt, daß man nicht weiß, welche Art von Unterschied gesucht wird: Grammatisch (±reflexiv, Akk. vs. Dat.), wörtliche oder übertragene Bedeutung, Bedeutung in spezifischem Kontext (rechtlich), Registerunterschiede (fachsprachlich), … Im schlimmsten Fall (der nicht selten auftritt) tauchen in der Frage nicht einmal Beispielsätze auf! Plädoyer: Die Fragen müssen besser werden, dann werden es die Antworten automatisch.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Ich denke, auch bei besseren und spezifischeren Fragen wird es Antworten geben, die nichts sagen außer: »Es gibt keinen Unterschied« und diese Antworten werden dieselben Probleme haben, als wären sie zur einer schlechteren Frage geschrieben.

Comment: Angenommen, es gäbe absolute Synonymität, ließe sich diese nicht beweisen. Sehr einfach dagegen dürfte es sein, das Gegenteil zu beweisen. Es genügt ein Gegenbeispiel. Das in einer eigenen Antwort auszuführen, steht jedem ebenso frei wie ein Downvote einer als falsch (oder sinnlos) erachteten Antwort. Zusammen mit der Möglichkeit, in Kommentaren Verbesserungen anzuregen, dürften ausreichende Mittel zur Verfügung stehen, die eine Sonderbehandlung solcher Antworten überflüssig machen.

Comment: @Olafant: Ganz so einfach ist das leider nicht. Das Gegenbeispiel muss man ja erst mal finden bzw. man muss den Unterschied in Worte fassen. Und bis dahin kann eine frühe Antwort, die absolute Synonymität behauptet, schon mal mehrere Upvotes Vorsprung anhäufen. Außerdem gibt es immer wieder dieselben Diskussionen.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Dann besteht das Problem also eher in möglicherweise unüberlegten Upvotes? Was spricht denn gegen Diskussionen? Dein in der Frage verlinktes [Beispiel](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1493/sprechen-von-synonymen-und-über-synonyme) spricht m.E. deutlich gegen das Löschen. Nach meinem Dafürhalten begründet *user unknown* sehr deutlich und nachvollziehbar, warum das Löschen der Antwort keine gute Entscheidung war. Möglicherweise hätten mehrere frühe Upvotes qualitativ minderwertige Antworten und deren (unüberlegte) Upvotes verhindert.

Comment: "Absolute Synonymität ist eine außerordentliche Behauptung" ist eine außerordentliche Behauptung und bedarf eines außerordentlichen Beweises. Am besten erklärst Du zum Warmwerden den Unterschied zw. Blaukraut und Rotkohl. Eine Grundannahme pro Unterschied ist nicht gerechtfertigt sondern im Einzelfall zu belegen, was ja sehr viel einfacher ist als das Gegenteil, weil ja ein einziges, funktionierendes Beispiel, genügt (ultraviolett aber nicht ultralila).